# How to convert the Function3 to hit 2 API's in parallel instead of 3 or more?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-android

I am using the following way to hit 3 API's in parallel as i can see there are like Function4,5,6 if you want to hit more API's but there is no Function2<..> so what to use for hitting 2 API's?

```
Observable.zip(
        backendApi.getFCdata("","","",""),
        backendApi.getAKCountry(),
        backendApi.getRecyclerData("","",""),
        Function3<ResponseGetFCData, ResponseAK, List<ResponseMarket>, List<ResponseMarket>> { 
            fcData, akCountry, recyclerData ->

            // Your operation here

            return recyclerData
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe { /* Loading Start */ }
        .doOnTerminate { /* Loading End */ }
        .subscribe(
                { /* Successfully Synced */ },
                { /* Having error */ }
        )
```

The converted form for 2 API's using above example will be a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `BiFunction` in this purpose. Check below:

```
Observable.zip(
    backendApi.getFCdata("","","",""),
    backendApi.getRecyclerData("","",""),
    BiFunction<ResponseGetFCData, List<ResponseMarket>, List<ResponseMarket>> {
        fcData, recyclerData ->

    // Your operation here

    return recyclerData
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnSubscribe { /* Loading Start */ }
.doOnTerminate { /* Loading End */ }
.subscribe(
    { /* Successfully Synced */ },
    { /* Having error */ }
)
```

Comment: Yes it is working but there seems to be one problem when I am using backendApi.getRecyclerData("","","") it is not working but when i define the whole url in getRecyclerData("https://....+""+""+"") and change the definition from getRecyclerData(@query) to getRecyclerData(@url) then it is working, what can be the issue?

Comment: while getFCdata(..) method is working fine with @query

Comment: That's not related to `Observable.zip`, it's related to Retrofit configuration. Have you used BASE_URL during configuration?

Comment: Not an issue. I ask to confirm whether you set or not. It's recommended. What's problem with `query`? Is there any log?